# After System Backup error Cannot login to admin

Tags: database, magento-1, exception, http-error-500

I was using `System > Back up`  tools to backup media and data file and it took too long to process so I closed the browser and now i cannot login to admin page.

Now first, admin page was `500 error` and after I deleted `var/cache/` and `var/session` admin page was back on but when I entered my id and password to login, page looks like it was loading for long time and at last,

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is
>   disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 382662642504

this msg came out.

So, I went `var/report` and it said

```
a:5:{i:0;s:91:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction";i:1;s:2839:"#0 lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `admin_u...', Array)
#4 lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `admin_u...', Array)
#5 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(632): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `admin_u...', Array)
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php(85): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('admin_user', Array, Array)
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php(376): Mage_Admin_Model_Resource_User->recordLogin(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_User))
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php(91): Mage_Admin_Model_User->login('admin', 'xxxxxxx')
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php(69): Mage_Admin_Model_Session->login('admin', 'xxxxxxx', Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Admin_Model_Observer->actionPreDispatchAdmin(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Observer), 'actionPreDispat...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(528): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(408): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#16 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}";s:3:"url";s:16:"/index.php/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 0):

even when you closed the browser, it was executing the script in backend. May you are having too heaving media or data which took it too long to execute and finally the timeout appeared.